# How to setup mysql on tmpfs?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

How to setup mysql on tmpfs ?

I am reading [a tutorial in french](http://monblog.system-linux.net/blog/2011/08/25/mettre-entierement-mysql-en-ram-grace-a-ramfs-ou-tmpfs/), where the author do it this way :

1.) Create a tmpfs directory :

```
mkdir /var/tmpfs
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G tmpfs /var/tmpfs
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/tmpfs/mysql
```

2.) Add it to fstab :

```
tmpfs  /var/tmpfs  tmpfs  nodev,nosuid,noexec,noatime,size=1G  0 0
```

3.) Copy MySQL to tmpfs (**is ramfs here is correct?**)

```
service mysql stop
cp -Rfv /var/lib/mysql /var/ramfs/
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/tmpfs/mysql
```

4.) Edit /etc/my.cnf

```
datadir /var/tmpfs/mysql
```

Then restart mysqld and you can optionally add a startup/stop script to backup the ram data to disk...

But I am not sure the above is right : did the writer of this tutorial mistake ramfs for tmpfs here ? He then goes on to use ramfs in the start/stop script, but what ramfs has to do there, isn't it really tmpfs only ?

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: To speed up Drupal's SimpleTests, it's really necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like it was really

```
cp -Rfv /var/lib/mysql /var/tmpfs/
```

Working great now.

Answer (score 2):

Before you try doing this: take a look at mysql's "memory" storage engine. I would stick with that rather than having to deal with the many edge cases with e tmpfs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html

we were considering the exact same scenario, but luckly ran across the memory engine, and have not had a problem since.

Comment: Don't you have to change every single database upgrade script in your app to use `ENGINE = MEMORY` this way?  Seems impossible to do if you're running tests differently to live code. The tmpfs solution seems like the only one

Comment: MySQL's "memory" storage engine does not support BLOB/TEXT fields. So for DB's with those, like the one I was working on, MEMORY storage is a non-starter.